# How to enable three finger swipe in linux (Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit)?

Tags: touchpad, debian-jessie, gestures

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit on my system. 
how to enable three finger swipe here, how can i set an event in three finget swipe ? 
**e.g** if i want to switch workspace in 3 finger swipe, how to do

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to install fusuma. Read more here: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-get-apple-like-gestures-on-the-linux-desktop/